# Cakephp3 Set Header in Email Component : Mails are going to spam

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I need to set headers as followings

```
$headers ="From:<$from>\n";
$headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers.="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso 8859-1";
```

how can i write it to Email component in cakephp3. Code is following

```
$this->email->emailFormat('html');
$this->email->from([$data['sender'] => $data['sender_name']]);
$this->email->to($to)
$this->email->subject($data['subject']);
$this->email->send();
```

I want this to prevent spam mail. Mails are going to spam .Thanks all .

Answer (score -1):

You can use set headers function-

$this->email->setHeaders(['From:\n','MIME-Version: 1.0\n','Content-type: text/html; charset=iso 8859-1']);

Comment: Problem is mail is going to spam . I don't think this code will add headers